# Destruturing overwriting exisiting values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I ma trying to update state in my reducer below.

The results object has two arrays:

```
results: {
    correctAnswers: [7]
    incorrectAnswers: (9) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
}
```

How can I add `totalScore` to the results object? The code below adds `totalScore`, but removes `correctAnswers` and `incorrectAnswers`.

```
case "COMPLETE_QUIZ": {
  const { totalScore, id } = action.data;
  console.log(action.data, state);
  return {
    videos: state.videos.map(video =>
      video.id === id
        ? {
            ...video,
            results: {
              totalScore \\ add here
            },
            completed: true
          }
        : video
    ),
    search: { term: "", videos: [] }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`spread` the original object and add a new property

```
results: {
    ...state.results,
    totalScore
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign(results, {totalScore stuff})` It'll merge the object left to right.